# How to gsub an unicode 0083 with ruby?

Tags: ruby, unicode, yaml, break, gsub

I have loaded a string from a html.file, and I have writen it to a yaml file with the plugin ya2yaml:

---

```
- title: 'What a wonderful day!'
  body:  ... # main contents here
```

---

and I will load the .yml file by YAML::parse_file method.
but "\n" in the string will cause load problems, so I tried to gsub all "\n" to "", but there is still problems, a char '0083'(I see it in the terminal) still breaks the line, and cause loading problem:

---

```
in `load': syntax error on line 32, col 6: `      </strong><br>ok ' (ArgumentError)
from /home/croplio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-preview3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:178:in `parse'
from /home/croplio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-preview3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:203:in `block in parse_file'
from /home/croplio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-preview3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:202:in `open'
```

---

So what's wrong with the yaml or the char 0083?
or how can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Try this: `# coding utf-8 ............... gsub("\u0083","")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0083 is a unicode character 'NO BREAK HERE'.
I don't know YAML::pars, but maybe you can switch it to use unicodes or use pure ascii codes.